# Is it possible to get coordinate system name from SQL Server geometry type?

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, srid, geometry-data-type

I need to get the name of the coordinate system of a geometry type field in SQL Server 2008 R2 (for example NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N or GCS_WGS_1984 or other). Is this possible?

Comment: Do you store your data in an Esri geodatabase or it is a pure SQL Server database?

Comment: It's pure SQL Server.

Comment: sys.spatial_reference_systems.  But mine only has GCS in it. I don't think SQL Server cares about planar systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2008, I usually do

`select SHAPE.STSrid from dbo.STATES`

(where SHAPE is the geometry column and dbo.states is the table name). It will give you SRID.

Now you can run

```
select * from sys.spatial_reference_systems where spatial_reference_id = 4326
```

However, as @Jay Cummins mentioned, it seems to have only geographic coordinate systems.
Link to the Microsoft forum: [Projected Coordinate System Support](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d698ca09-b683-45d2-8998-6f335c9c1fa7/projected-coordinate-system-support?forum=sqlspatial)

If you would have an Esri geodatabase, you could see the projected coordinate system SRID and the name with definition from ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS which is created when creating a geodatabase repository.

[image]